# Stuck trying to create new dictionary from 2 lists - 1 of tuples, 1 for dictionary keys

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

I have 2 lists. `a` is a list of tuples that I would like to transform into a dictionary that retains 'a' values as lists - using the second list as the dictionary keys. I've tried using the `a's` first set as 'index' values in the tuple list to marry to the 'key' values in the `b` list.
This is what I have:

```
a = [(0, ['Potato'], [8]),
     (0, ['Tomato'], [2]),
     (0, ['Tomato'], [2]),
     (0, ['Potato'], [6]),
     (0, ['Potato'], [12]),
     (0, ['Potato'], [12]),
     (0, nan, nan),
     (1, [], []),
     (1, [], [])]

b = [('foo', 123), ('bar', 456)]
```

This is what I'm trying to get:

```
newDict = {'foo' : [(['Potato'], ['Tomato'], ['Tomato'], ['Potato'], ['Potato'], ['Potato'], nan), ([8], [2], [2], [6], [12], [12], nan)], 
           'bar' : [([], []),([],[])]}
```

I've tried enumerating through various for loops, unzipping the tuples.

Comment: The logic seems inconsistent. Why in the output `[[], []]` and not `[[[], []], [[], []]]`? I mean, there are *four* empty lists in the input, so where did two of them go?

Comment: Example updated

Comment: And why `'Patato'` and not `['Patato']` -- which was the original value?

Comment: I thought the earlier example made more sense if we follow group by pattern on lists of 0 index.

Comment: The outcome hasn't changed, the formatting was adjusted in the output to reflect the formatting in 'a'

Comment: Can you explain in words how `b` picks items from `a` to translate to `newDict`? Do you want the tuples whose first element is the index of `('foo', 123)` to be translated into the `foo` key, and the tuples whose first element is the index of `('bar', 456)` to translate into the `bar` key ? If this is the case, there seems to be an extra `['Potato']` in the list for the `foo` key

Comment: b[0][0] = 'foo', which is matched with a[0][0] such that iterating through the first values of the tuples in b gives the new dictionary key, the secondary values in 'b' are not needed by the newDict. They are there as placeholders to create a tuple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use group by (from itertools) to group the tuples from `a` based on their first entry, then zip that to `b` to pair up the 'foo' and 'bar' with the corresponding 0 and 1 groups:

```
a = [(0, ['Potato'], [8]),
     (0, ['Tomato'], [2]),
     (0, ['Tomato'], [2]),
     (0, ['Potato'], [6]),
     (0, ['Potato'], [12]),
     (0, ['Potato'], [12]),
     (0, 'nan', 'nan'),
     (1, [], []),
     (1, [], [])]

b = [('foo', 123), ('bar', 456)]


from itertools import groupby

r = {tb[0]:list(zip(*ta))[1:] for tb,(_,ta) in zip(b,groupby(a,lambda t:t[0]))}

print(r)
{'foo': 
  [(['Potato'], ['Tomato'], ['Tomato'], ['Potato'], ['Potato'], ['Potato'], 'nan'), 
   ([8], [2], [2], [6], [12], [12], 'nan')], 
 'bar': 
  [([], []), ([], [])]}
```